# C++: Last digit in an exponent - wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to implement a simple program that takes base and exponent and output the last digit of a result of exponentiation, but online judge says that my program gives wrong answers. What could be wrong?

P.S. The constraint of a program must be 700 kb which is not a problem here (I can erase spaces and comments and use one-letter variables to avoid that problem)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t; // t - number of test cases
    cin >> t;
    cin.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    {
        int base, exp; // base - base, exp - exponent
        cin >> base >> exp;
        cin.get();

        if (exp == 0)
            cout << 1 << endl;

        else if (base % 10 == 0)
            cout << 0 << endl;

        else if (base % 10 == 1)
            cout << 1 << endl;

        else if (base % 10 == 5)
            cout << 5 << endl;

        else if (base % 10 == 6)
            cout << 6 << endl;

        else if (base % 10 == 2 || base % 10 == 3 || base % 10 == 7 || base % 10 == 8)
        {
            int pattern = exp % 4; // pattern repeats every 4th exponent
            int lastDigit = base; // lastDigit - result of program

            if (pattern == 0)
                pattern = 4;

            for (int i = 1; i < pattern; ++i)
                lastDigit = (lastDigit * base) % 10;

            cout << lastDigit << endl;
        }


        else if (base % 10 == 4 || base % 10 == 9)
        {
            int pattern = exp % 2; // pattern repeats every 2nd exponent
            int lastDigit = base; // lastDigit 0 result of program

            if (pattern == 0)
                pattern = 2;

            for (int i = 1; i < pattern; ++i)
                lastDigit = (lastDigit * base) % 10;

            cout << lastDigit << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are samples.

```
INPUT

3 10
6 2
7 3123123
0 1
1 0
0 0


OUTPUT

9
6
3
0
1
1
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Original problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASTDIG/

Comment: You should add the test cases that it outputs the wrong answers for; otherwise you're effectively asking SO to debug your application without anything to go on.

Comment: i don't have any, if i had, i would debug it myself, but for every input that i give it gives correct answer. the thing is online judge is complaining, sorry

Comment: If you haven't done already, test it on every corner case you can think of.

Comment: i had, and it works, seriosly

Comment: Well what have you tried. Probably the most used comment in SO.

Comment: maybe i'm missing some cases, what tricky cases can cause my program to give wrong answers?

Comment: i'll edit the question to include my input and output

Comment: Maybe you need to allow floats (decimals)?

Comment: Can you show the case which it falis on? And what's the output?

Comment: What range of numbers can the inputs be in?

Comment: Can base or exponent be bigger than 2^31-1? If so then you should use 64-bit ints rather than current 32-bit

Comment: Can you include the exact problem statement? Otherwise we are forced to half-guess (and inherit whatever invalid assumptions about the inputs you *might* have made).

Comment: http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASTDIG/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
int lastDigit = base; // lastDigit - result of program
```

You should take the modulo by 10 to get the last digit.

You do perform a modulo by 10 later, but not in all cases (not when the for loop doesn't need any iteration). So in some cases, your code will output a number that is more than one digit.

Answer (score 5):

This code fails when `lastDigit * base` overflows.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I would just do `base %= 10;` once shortly after reading it. That eliminates several other `% 10` expressions as well.

Comment: i guess it is not a problem since base is in range from 1 to 20